# Difference between `test -n $a` and `test -n "$a"`

Tags: bash, shell

```
$ a=""
$ test -n $a
$ echo $?
0
$ test -n a
$ echo $?
0
$ test -n "$a"
$ echo $?
1
```

What is the difference between them? Why are the results different?

Answer (score 7):

When `$a` is empty, `test -n $a` expands to this:

```
'test' '-n'
```

When `test` only receives one argument like this, it does the default test, which is probably the source of your confusion. The default test is the same as `-n`, i.e. the following two are equivalent:

```
test string
test -n string
```

So your test is whether the string `-n` has a length greater than zero. It does, so you get a `0` exit status.

Your next example:

```
'test' '-n' 'a'
```

tests whether the length of the literal string `a` is greater than zero. It is, so you get a `0` exit status again.

The final test is probably what you wanted all along. It expands to this:

```
'test' '-n' ''
```

Now two arguments are passed, but the second one is empty, so the `-n` test fails and you get a `1` exit status.

#### Conclusion

Always quote your variables!

---

You can view how the shell expands your statement using `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ test -n $a
+ test -n
$ test -n "$a"
+ test -n ''
```

Comment: So `test -n $a` actually tests the length of `$a` without expanding the it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly but `$a` expands to nothing, so has no effect on the command.

Comment: @Vinny It isn't `$a` that is passed to `test`, it is the expanded value. `test` itself sees no different between `a="foo bar"; test -n $foo` and `test -n foo bar`, received three arguments `-n`, `foo`, and `bar` in both cases. Likewise, it sees no difference between `test -n "$a"` and `test -n "foo bar"`, getting two arguments `-n` and `foo bar` in both cases.

Comment: @yang.zhou Only by coincidence. `test -z ""` exits successfully because `""` is an empty string. `test -z` exits successfully because `-z` is *not* an empty string.

Comment: But 'text -z' can output correct answer `a =''; test -z $a; echo $?; 0`

Comment: @yang.zhou the important point is that if `$a` is empty, then you are just running `test -z`, which is the same as `test -n -z`, so it is successful (`-z` is a string with length greater than 0). It's the same behavior as the first example in my answer.

Comment: @yang.zhou It will not output the correct answer if `a=foo*`, the `nullglob` option is set, and there are no files in the working directory that match `foo*`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's play a game called "Count the arguments". How many arguments does `test` receive in the call

```
test -n $a
```

If you said "2" (meaning `-n` and `$a`), sorry, that's incorrect. The correct answer is "We don't know".

We don't know because we don't know what the value of the parameter `a` is. If `a=foo`, then `test` receives two arguments, `-n` and `foo`. If `a="foo bar"`, then `test` gets *three* arguments after word-splitting takes place, `-n`, `foo`, and `bar`.

What if `a=*`? The if you said "2, `-n` and `*`", you get points for trying, but you are still wrong. That's because the result of expanding `$a`, if it contains certain characters like `*`, undergoes not just word-splitting, but pathname expansion as well. There is no way to tell how many arguments `test` will get without knowing how many files are in the current working directory, because `*` will expand to a sequence of file names, one word per file.

By contrast, `test -n "$a"` always passes two arguments to `test`. The *quoted* parameter expansion is not subject to word-splitting or pathname expansion, so whatever value `a` has (`foo`, `foo bar`, or `*`), that exact string is always passed to `test` as a single argument.